# Save state systems

Tags: amiga

With an Amiga A500, Action Replay cartridge (v1.5 or later) and memory expansion, it was possible to save a copy of the state of memory, much like a save state in an emulator (or snapshot in a virtual machine?). Were there any other systems that allowed save states in a physical hardware / non-emulator environment?

Comment: Cross-post https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/20396

Comment: Yeah, on the one hand it's something only used for gaming (as far as I'm aware) but on the other hand there's presumably nothing to stop you from saving the state of anything, even a Workbench session. So fits nicely in either I guess?